# jquery removing items from array after they are added in drag area

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using jquery ui for dragging items, so I have an array similar to:

```
var animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'monkey'];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '</p>');
}
$('#list').html(output.join(""));
```

So I get this on the page, what I want to do is if I drag "cat" to dragging zone, I would like to remove it from the array automatically. New array should have only "dog" and "monkey" in it and that should be showed on the page.

```
 <div class="col-xs-2">
   <a href="#">
      <img id="drag-cat" class="drag-img" src="images/cat.png" alt="" />
   </a>  
 </div>
```

That is my html part, so when I drag it and this item is showed in that drag div, I would like to update array.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th01sw16/)

Comment: Where is your script ? Do share working demo...

Comment: Ok, I will create jsfiddle now. Will post link shortly.

Comment: @Rayon I added the link, please check, thanks. One note, it is not perfect but if you drag over that gray are it will add them to that animals-box

Comment: @Morpheus have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/n7e076jt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `Array#splice` to remove `item` from array by specifying the `index`
- Use `String#split` to get `name` from `id` attribute as there is no other reference
- Re-bind the `output` array considering removed `item`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag-main img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
      var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
    }
  });
  $(".animals-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(".animals-box img").length == 0) {
        $(".animals-box").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      var elem = ui.draggable[0].getAttribute('id').split('-')[1];
      animals.splice(animals.indexOf(elem), 1);
      var output = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '</p>');
      }
      $('#list').html(output.join(""));
      $(".animals-box").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
var animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'monkey'];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '</p>');
}
$('#list').html(output.join(""));
```

```css
.drag-main img {
  width: 75px;
}
.animals-box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.animals-box img {
  float: left;
}
.draggable {
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.dropped {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="drag-main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="drag-cat" class="drag-img" src="http://i.amz.mshcdn.com/KRUEW_Zm_0UvTD97QnKID9MUqmk=/150x150/2012%2F12%2F04%2Fd0%2Fcat.c4A" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="drag-dog" class="drag-img" src=" http://www.dogisto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/dog-abandoned-150x150.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="animals-box"></div>
<hr>
<div id="list">
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/th01sw16/1/)

---

**Using `data-*` attribute**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag-main img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
      var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
    }
  });
  $(".animals-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(".animals-box img").length == 0) {
        $(".animals-box").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      var elem = ui.draggable[0].dataset.name;
      animals.splice(animals.indexOf(elem), 1);
      var output = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '</p>');
      }
      $('#list').html(output.join(""));
      $(".animals-box").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
var animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'monkey'];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '</p>');
}
$('#list').html(output.join(""));
```

```css
.drag-main img {
  width: 75px;
}
.animals-box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.animals-box img {
  float: left;
}
.draggable {
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.dropped {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="drag-main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="drag-cat" data-name="cat" class="drag-img" src="http://i.amz.mshcdn.com/KRUEW_Zm_0UvTD97QnKID9MUqmk=/150x150/2012%2F12%2F04%2Fd0%2Fcat.c4A" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="drag-dog" data-name="dog" class="drag-img" src=" http://www.dogisto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/dog-abandoned-150x150.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="animals-box"></div>
<hr>
<div id="list">
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but I have a problem, what if my array has name like "Mountain Lion", and id of element can't be like that, instead it is mountain-lion, how can I solve this issue? Or if name is like "Something & else" or "Something / else" ?Thank you very much.

Comment: @Morpheus, I will suggest you to have `data_*` attribute..Check the edit..

Comment: And one more thing, since I asked about calculator, last issue that I have is how can I add, default values like 0 on the right side of that "animals" array and that field should be editable, for example user should be able to enter a number in there, cat 1, dog 2, monkey 22, so I can have a total number below which would be in this case 25... If you want I will edit my question and add this info in there.... Thank you.

Comment: @Morpheus, That has to be another question with details about what you have tried...

Comment: Ok, I will post it now, please be here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dropped elemenent id and remove it from the array in the drop event like:

```
var index = animals.indexOf( ui.draggable.attr("id").replace('drag-',''));
animals.splice(index, 1);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/th01sw16/2/