# jquery calculator with editable field from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Based on previous answer on another question, the next step is adding mini calculator...

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '<input class="pull-right" value="0" />' + '</p>');
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvtxrf98/2/)

I was trying to get value of input with jquery val() but without success... 
Any other suggestion?

As you can see in jsfiddle list is like:

cat   0

dog 0

monkey 0

Total:

So if user updates cat to be 2 and dog to be 1, I would like to show 3 in total.

Thanks.

EDIT: 
[Link to previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178096/jquery-removing-items-from-array-after-they-are-added-in-drag-area/38178700)

Comment: Do you need total. when you out of any text box? I mean when i write 2 in cat text box and push tab then it will give me reflection in total. right?

Comment: what is the draggable purpose?

Comment: Can you explain (or link to) your previous question? I have no idea what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjayaraj/yvtxrf98/14/)

In the text box change event please add a function as below

```
$(".animals-input").change(function(e) {
  calculator();
});

function calculator()
{
  var result = parseInt(0);
  $(".animals-input").each(function(){
    result = result + parseInt($(this).val());
    $("#total-animals").html("Total:"+result);
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Inorder to reset the total dragging you need to add my calculator method in your droppable event.So your code would look like this

```
$(".animals-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(".animals-box img").length == 0) {
        $(".animals-box").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      var elem = ui.draggable[0].getAttribute('id').split('-')[1];
      animals.splice(animals.indexOf(elem), 1);
      var output = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '<input class="pull-right" value="0" />' + '</p>');
      }
      $('#list').html(output.join(""));
      $(".animals-box").append(ui.draggable);
      $('#list').html(output.join(""));
      calculator(); // Add this method into your existing code you will get the result.
    }
  });
});
```

This is a sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjayaraj/yvtxrf98/15/). Please check if it works for you

I hope this would help you.

Comment: This is good but again I have a problem when I remove one animal from the list with that draggable, and result stays the same... Let me explain by example: cat 1, dog 2 = result 3, that is good. If I remove cat, dog value resets to 0, which is good, but result is still 3, which is not good. After I enter 1 for dog, result is recalculated... and it shows 1, which is good... So I need to fix it when one animal is removed, that should reset whatever is in that function... Any suggestions?

Comment: May I know how you are removing

Comment: It may be helpful to explain here as well. If you move cat or dog image on that gray area, they should be removed from the list below... That is it... I have that working so I just need a way to reset the result when new list is created...

Comment: Let me try and let you know

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check and let me know if it works

Comment: It is working, just one more thing :-) If I need it for future usage if I change parseInt to parseFloat, how can I limit to show only 2 numbers after decimal? so 1.01 + 1.02 => 2.0300000000000002? I tried using toFixed(2) but it won't work, any ideas?

Comment: Let me try and I will let you know

Comment: I could get the correct result by using toFixed(2). Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kjayaraj/yvtxrf98/16/

Answer (score 0):

You have input fields from which you want to get the value and add the total and show it in the total field. 
You may want to add a button that upon clicking calls a js function which gets the values from all the fields and adds them and then finally appends the value to the "#total-animals".

```
<button type="button">Add</button>

var total=0;
$('button').click(function() {  
    //you may want to make a loop here and provide each of the input fields some id.
    //inside the loop:
        total+=$("#id_of_input_field).val();
    //when the loop ends do this.
    var el="<div>total="+total+</div>";
    $("#total-animals").append(el);
 }
```

Comment: You can also simply bind the keyup/change events. No button needed. :)

Comment: yeah, its just a choice of preference :)

Answer (score 0):

Because I am not sure what the drag & drop code purpose, I delete it in below fiddle.

You can check the fiddle link.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvtxrf98/5/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  output.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '<input class="animals-input pull-right" data-id='+animals[i]+' value="0" />' + '</p>');
}
$('#list').html(output.join(""));

$(".animals-input").change(function(e) {
  var number = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
  var animal = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-id");
  animalTotal[animal] = number;
  countTotal(animalTotal);
})

function countTotal(total) {
  var t = 0;
  for(var i in total) {
    t += total[i];
  }
  $("#total-animals").html("Total:"+t);
}
```

The different part is I will append a animal id at each input to recognize which input value is changed.

It can calculate the total value when input value changed.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for me, let me check shortly and I will let you know...

Comment: Maybe it's because I use `change` to bind the input, so you need to blur the input after your change then it will calculate result again.

Comment: the problem is that when I remove item with drag from the array, I no longer get total number, I only get last entered number... example: I removed cat, now I have dog and monkey, if I enter dog: 2 and monkey 1, result will be 1, which is wrong..

Comment: Drag and drop purpose is that to remove item from the array if it is not necessary...

Comment: I was able to solve most of the issues, now I only have one, how can I reset whatever value is in countTotal function, before I use it again on different place? The problem is when I use drag to drop some animals from the list, and that new list contains previous result... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this at the end of your js.

You should test the user input if he enters something else than numbers. You also need to put a class in your input text if you use it in your page for another purpose.

```
$('input:text').on('change',function(){
    var total = 0;
    $("input:text").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

  $('#total-animals').html("Total: " + total);
});
```

Comment: This is not good, what if I decide to change value of cat several times? it will be added automatically and result will be wrong...

Comment: @Morpheus My mistake, sorry :) I updated the answer, hope it works better.